# DELETE FROM `table` AS `alias` ... WHERE `alias`.`column` ... why syntax error?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, alias

I tried this with MySQL:

```
DELETE FROM `contact_hostcommands_relation` AS `ContactHostCommand` WHERE (`ContactHostCommand`.`chr_id` = 999999) LIMIT 1
```

And I get this:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (`ContactHostCommand`.`chr_id` = 999999) LIMIT 1' at line 1
```

*Note:* This query is automatically generated and conditions are based on table aliases.

Why I get this error?

Is there any way to use table aliases in where clause?

Is this MySQL specific?

Comment: Try the same without `AS`. Just remove it.

Comment: @sp00m I tried but is not working. Thanks for the idea anyway.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use SQL like this:

```
DELETE FROM ContactHostCommand 
USING `contact_hostcommands_relation` AS ContactHostCommand 
WHERE (ContactHostCommand.`chr_id` = 999999) 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Nice. Is this MySQL specific?

Comment: Don't really know as I only needed this in MySQL. My guess this is a MySQL workaround for not supporting DELETE from alias.

Comment: for MSSQL:
DELETE ContactHostCommand FROM `contact_hostcommands_relation` AS ContactHostCommand

Comment: Got the following error: `#1109 Unknown table 'category' in MULTI DELETE`. SQL: `delete from category using category as c where c.id = 'a'`.

Answer (score 46):

What @Matus and @CeesTimmerman said about MSSQL, works in MySQL 5.1.73 too:

```
delete <alias> from <table> <alias> where <alias>.<field>...
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use `AS` in a `DELETE` clause with MySQL :

```
DELETE FROM `contact_hostcommands_relation` WHERE (`chr_id` = 999999) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It works. But I needed table aliases for specifying conditions for the query builder. Now I am using a special variable that holds the current model name. The model name is different than the table name. Is a question of homogeneity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use Alias on MySQL, try with:

```
DELETE <alias_name> FROM <alias_table> <alias_name> WHERE <alias_name>.nameofcolumn LIKE '%XXXXX%'
```