# How to join a table to find the items which do not exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql

my question may seem strange. But I have a question, how should I do a JOIN on a table for the following purpose:

I have a table called `categories`.

I have another pivot table called `categories_products`

Regularly I do a left join to get the categories of one product.

Now, after several month, there are some categories deleted from `categories` table. I had forgot to put a trigger at that time (that delete all related `categories_products` records of the deleted cat). I want to delete any record (which now is considered to be unused) from `categories_products` where its categories item is deleted (does not exist). What query should I write? Nothing comes to my mind. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
delete from categories_products cp 
where not exists (select 1 from categories c where c.id = cp.category_id);
```

Or

```
delete from categories_products cp 
where cp.category_id not in (select distinct c.id from categories c);
```

But EXISTS is usually faster.

Comment: it seems there exists a syntax error in your first code

Comment: @Mostafa Talebi You're welcome. Yes, there can be some problems with a table alias in DELETE clause: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484532/delete-from-table-as-alias-where-alias-column-why-syntax-error

Answer (score 1):

DELETE categories_products
 where id not in (select * from (select c.id form  categories_products cp 
  JOIN categories c
 ON cp.categories_id =c.id)x);

Answer (score 0):

This multi-table delete should be even faster as it doesn't require a subquery (which MySQL usually isn't good at):

```
DELETE categories_products
 FROM categories_products
 LEFT JOIN categories
 ON categories_products.categories_id = categories.id
 HAVING categories.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: MySQL multi table DELETE syntax doesn't support HAVING :(