# MySQL Query fails. Error message does not show my full query--cuts off at string

Tags: mysql

When I attempt to run the following query in phpmyadmin or directly in the cli,

```
DELETE FROM mdl_enrol n1 WHERE n1.id > (
    SELECT n2.id from mdl_enrol n2
    WHERE n2.enrol = "database"
    AND n1.id > n2.id
    AND n2.courseid = n1.courseid
)
AND n1.enrol = "database"
```

I get the following error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'n1 WHERE n1.id > (SELECT n2.id from mdl_enrol n2 WHERE n2.enrol = "da' at line 1
```

If I run the command as a SELECT * it works fine and returns the right number of rows.

Why does this keep cutting off partway through my string "database"?

Comment: that's because error messages just give you a SNIPPET of the sql causing the problem. it's never the entire query, unless your query is short enough to fit inside the normal error message length limit.

Comment: SQL errors don't return the entire query string, just enough to point out where your error is. If they did, it'd be a HUGE security issue.

Comment: The error in your query is that you are aliasing the table in your delete statement incorrectly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484532/delete-from-table-as-alias-where-alias-column-why-syntax-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, MySQL doesn't return the whole query in error message. And you don't need it as you already know which query you are submitting (if it was done e.g. via PHP, you could "echo" the query before executing). MySQL always returns the query from the first character which caused the error.

In your case, the error is in `... mdl_enrol`**`n1`**`...`. According to [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html), in `DELETE`syntax, you are not allowed to specify table aliases as in `SELECT` queries. So you have to rewrite your query without the `n1` alias and use only the full table name `mdl_enrol`.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, thanks for pointing out my noob mistake all :) I was having some other issues with PHPmyadmin cutting off my saved queries so I thought the two were related somehow and it was frustrating me!

Anyway, I found a solution to my query, working off of Marki555's answer. I had to modify my query as so:

```
DELETE n1 FROM mdl_enrol AS n1 WHERE n1.id > (
    SELECT n2.id FROM (
        SELECT * FROM mdl_enrol
        ) AS n2
    WHERE n2.enrol = "database"
    AND n1.id > n2.id
    AND n2.courseid = n1.courseid
)
AND n1.enrol = "database"
```

Yes, the DELETE syntax does not directly allow you to use aliases, but you can use the AS syntax.

Then I ran into the issue of not being allowed to define an alias within the WHERE clause (for n2) so I had to create a separate FROM clause within the WHERE clause that defines mdl_enrol (using SELECT * FROM mdl_enrol) as n2

This was taken from [this guide](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/)

Thanks for the help!