# Ebean ExpressionList.delete creating incorrect SQL?

Tags: mysql, ebean

My team recently upgraded to a newer version of Ebean (6.8.1) and I was trying out some of the new features.  I saw that ExpressionList.delete is now available, but it doesn't work for me.  Here's an example:

```
NewResponse.find.where().le("complete", startTime).delete();
```

When I run this command, I get a SQL syntax error:

```
delete from new_response t0 where t0.complete <= ?
```

I tested this out on my local database and that command (with the parameter filled in at the ? symbol) fails there, too. After doing some research, it seems an alias can't be used that way with a DELETE FROM (ex [DELETE FROM `table` AS `alias` ... WHERE `alias`.`column` ... why syntax error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484532/delete-from-table-as-alias-where-alias-column-why-syntax-error)).

Is this a bug in Ebean? A limitation of my version of eBean/mySQL? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this bug was fixed in 7.2.1: https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/583